# Help needed to write SQL Query for SQL Logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to write SQL Query to Retrive the Following Settings of SQL Logins for SQL server 2005:

> 1.Enforce password policy
>
> 2.Enforce password expiration
>
> 3.User must change password at next login

Thanx in advance.

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_logins
```

should give you the first two (is_policy_checked and is_expiration_checked columns)

and you can use `SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('sa', 'IsMustChange')` to find if the user must change password at next login

So putting it all into one query...

```
SELECT name,
    is_policy_checked,
    is_expiration_checked, 
    LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'IsMustChange') as is_must_change
FROM   sys.sql_logins
```